# Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS - Mac OS X

Tags: c++

When I'm comparing an element in std::vector to char, I randomly get this error sometimes when running to program (about once every five times):

> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>
> Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
>
> 0x0000000100017c49 in randomCaveGenerator (p=@0x7fff5fbff51c, q=@0x7fff5fbff518, seed=1234567) at src/main.cpp:198
> 198             if (lm.map[1][i][j] == '0')

v is defined as a std::vector with all elements filled. I know this error usually means it is pointing to a null pointer <strike>but I know there shouldn't be one</strike>.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8, gdb to debug, and Apple LLVM version 4.2 (based on LLVM 3.2svn) to compile.

**Edit**

The code that I'm using:

```
typedef std::vector< std::vector<char> > MapGrid;

struct LevelMap
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<MapGrid> map;
    sf::Vector2u size;
};


LevelMap randomCaveGenerator(int p=64, int q=64, unsigned long seed=1)
{

    if (p < 64)
         p = 64;
    if (q < 64)
         q = 64;

    int groundLevel = 12;

    srand(seed);

    sf::Vector2u size(p, q);
    std::vector<MapGrid> mapG(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        mapG[i] = MapGrid(size.x, std::vector<char>(size.y));

        for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
            {
                 mapG[i][x][y] = '0';
            }
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
        {
            mapG[0][x][y] = 'v'; // Void Tile
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
        {
            mapG[2][x][y] = '0'; // Air Tile
        }
    }

    for (int y = groundLevel; y < size.y; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
        {
            int e = 23;
            if (2+(rand()%e)< e/2)
                mapG[1][x][y] = 'd';
            else
                mapG[1][x][y] = '0';

        }
    }

    LevelMap lm;
    lm.name = "Random Map";
    lm.map = mapG;
    lm.size = size;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        doSimStep(lm);

    for (int i = 1; i < lm.size.x - 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 12+groundLevel; j++)
        {
            if (lm.map[1][i][j] == '0') // PART WHERE THE ERROR IS
                continue;
            else
            {
                lm.map[1][i][j] = 'g';
                lm.map[2][i][j-1] = 'w';
                i++;
                j = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < lm.size.x - 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = groundLevel; j < lm.size.y - 2; j++)
        {
            if (lm.map[1][i][j] == 'd')
            {
                if (rand()%120 == 0)
                    lm.map[2][i][j] = 'p';
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lm.size.y; i++)
    {
        lm.map[1][0][i] = 'X';
        lm.map[1][lm.size.x-2][i] = 'X';
        lm.map[2][0][i] = '0';
        lm.map[2][lm.size.x-2][i] = '0';

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lm.size.x; i++)
    {
        lm.map[1][i][0] = 'X';
        lm.map[1][i][lm.size.y-2] = 'X';
        lm.map[2][i][0] = '0';
        lm.map[2][i][lm.size.y-2] = '0';

    }

    return lm;
}
```

Comment: We can't possibly help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Famous last words "I *know* there shouldn't be one".  Of course this means *that* is the problem:   you aren't seeing it because you know it can't be there.

Comment: Most likely, `i` is out of the valid range. But post the code, and we can perhaps give a better idea.

Comment: `but I know there shouldn't be one` Well, there is!

Comment: It is far better to treat all code as suspected of being guilty rather than granting any of it amnesty.

Comment: @Ginger Bill which line is 118? I can't see  if (lm.map[1][i][j] == '0') in there.

Comment: @doctorlove I've a comment to the like that caused the error. I'm sorry for poor post (not including code, changing the error, and now posting an old version of the code). In future posts, I will make sure not to do any of the errors.

Comment: Why do the loops sometimes start at 0 and sometimes at 1?

Comment: @doctorlove I sometimes start at 1 as there is no need to check at the 0 sometimes as this is will be a border/boundary to the randomized cave map. It should still work if those 1s are changed to 0s.

Answer (score 3):

With no source code apart from the error message

```
 if (v[i] == '0')
```

I can only imagine `i >= v.size()`

You might want to consider using iterators to access your vector, so you don't step off the end.

Comment: Just as likely is that `i < 0`.

Comment: Or `v` is somehow "broken".

Comment: Oh the error in the question has now changed, but it's similar. I give up